# Joist hangers to use for rough cut 2x8 (2 3/4" x 8 3/4")?

Tags: joists

I'm looking for the right size joist hangers for my project. I have an old house with rough cut oversized joists and can't seem to find a joist hangers that will work. I'm nailing into a 2x10 ledger.

The joist actual dimensions are: 2 3/4" w x 8 3/4" h

[image]

Comment: [Quote](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/joist-hangers-to-use-for-rough-cut-2x8-2-3-4-x-8-3-4#comment281253_166180) from Simpson: "not necessarily the dimensions of the joist".... which is more like 2-5/8"; a situation where you'd probably want a 2-3/4" hanger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpson Strong-Tie makes a “Face-Mount” joist hanger for “rough lumber” that can be custom ordered up to 8” wide.

It’s their HU Series. When ordering just add an “X” after the “normal” size you’d use. (Example: HU28X  and then specify the width required.)

Btw, you can use the HU load tables for determining allowable loads they’ll resist and use the same fasteners, (i.e.: SD Strong Drive Connector Screw or substitute 10d common or 16d sinkers, where noted in the charts.)

Comment: Hm, I'm confused by this. Does that mean I can customize the size of my hanger order?  The website says "HU hangers can be ordered in rough sizes at full table loads. Add "X" to the model designation (e.g., HU28X) and specify rough width or height. Maximum width 8"."

Comment: What is the actual width of a hu28x ?

Comment: @JohnAugust Yes, they are “custom” when you add the “X”

Comment: @JohnAugust You determine the width when you add the “X”. It can be any width you need, up to 8”.

Comment: That part about the X comes from [this catalog page](https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/19syk66yrg/C-C-2019-p113.pdf).  The size chart for rough cut ties only contains the U and LU model of hangers (which really comes down to the profile and screw pattern) so that note is saying that if you really want an HU tie in one of those rough-cut sizes, you can order it.  I think you'd be limited to those sizes (2, 4, 6, 8) and couldn't get a truly custom size.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes, you can get custom width HU joist hangers. Look at footnote (3) at the bottom of the page you referenced.

Comment: I've called Simpson before and they were very helpful. If you're not sure how to order I would give them a call.

Comment: I did one better and got it in writing, yes they can be custom sized: "Thank you for contacting Simpson Strong-Tie with your inquiry regarding hangers for rough sawn lumber. You are correct, we can modify "HU" face mount hangers.  Just specify the exact custom width and height dimensions of the "HU" hanger, (not necessarily the dimensions of the joist)."...."See pages 100-112 in the Wood Construction Connectors catalog C-C-2019 for our published load tables.  See also page 22 for load adjustment factors for optional fasteners you may require with just a single 2x ledger."

Comment: Link: https://www.strongtie.com/resources/literature/wood-construction-connectors-catalog

Comment: What's the 28 mean in *HU28X*? (nice name for a wood guy. There's a store by me called *Lee Lumber* - which probably has these in stock, unlike HD)

Comment: @Mazura The 28 means 2x8. You can change that to 26 for smaller joist hangers. However, when you add the “X” at the end, you must also add the custom width and height.

Answer (score 5):

I'm leaving my original answer below in case anyone is trying to hang a 1.75" board, but the question does clearly state 2.75", so, here is another option.

They do make joist hangers that are meant to hang [doubled-up joists](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-LUS-ZMAX-Galvanized-Face-Mount-Joist-Hanger-for-Double-2x8-LUS28-2Z/100375219).  These will be wide enough to handle 3 1/8" (hanger dimensions are [here](https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/fba12pkj4d/C-C-2019-p104-108.pdf) and have 1/8" of play for the doubled up joists that should be 3").

The extra 3/8" of width will be divided to 3/16" on either side, which shouldn't be a major concern.  You could cut some 1/4-3/8" shim stock if you're worried about the slop.  Strong-Tie also makes "rough sawn" hangers, but they measure 2" and 4" respectively (single and double hangers), so I think the standard double hanger is best here.

[image]

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER

The only thing that comes to mind immediately are decorative joist hangers used for decks and pergolas [such as these](https://www.decksdirect.com/6-8-in-laredo-sunset-joist-hanger-by-ozco-ornamental-wood-ties.html).

[image: joist hanger]

These are made for decorative cedar that doesn't conform to the 1.5" standard that all framing lumber uses.  If you look at the [specifications](https://www.decksdirect.com/documentation/ozco-ls-6-8-joist-hanger-measurements.pdf) for these particular hangers, they will accept lumber that is sized from 1.5" to 1.88".  Your 1.75" fits nicely in that range.  A standard joist hanger will only accept 1.5", as you have figured out.

Now, that one brand is just a random example that I have never used but your local home store and other online retailers should have similar products.  You do need to get more detailed specs on the hanger you choose to determine its structural ability.  These are not purely decorative - they do need to hold together pergolas and the like, but I am not sure if they are as strong as the typical galvanized joist hangers that are normally used.

Comment: The OP's joists are **2**.75", not 1.75".

Comment: @brhans, yea that certainly makes a difference...

Comment: Updated answer with an option for the correct size.

Comment: I suspect that it's important for the member being suspended to fit snugly in the hanger, otherwise more sag is likely across the saddle of the hanger. I'd definitely shim the gap, but it would probably work fine to shim to one side or the other.

Comment: This is also an option as there are 200 in stock at my local HD, but I will try to investigate the custom hanger option. I've seen them shimmed as you mentioned or even left with the gap. Example from TOH: http://tinypic.com/r/jjy2o6/9